# RowSelectionChanged-Event on entering an editable cell ( requirement:depending F4 OVS )

Tags: events, grid, abap, webdynpro

First things first:

If I click into a NOT editable cell in a WebDynpro grid, its parent ( the entire row ) gets selected.
For that it is properly set up in the layout painter ( row selectable = true ) .

If I click into an editable cell, nothing like this happens.
Instead the cursor prompt appears allowing me to edit the cell according to the assigned cell-editor.

But I need this selection-changed event also for editable cells.

Because, if the user chooses the F4 in that cell, there shall only be values available, which depend on another cell-value in this specific selected row.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way to implement your requirement:

1. Make IF_FPM_GUIBB_OVS implementation **directly** in the grid (in the `IF_FPM_GUIBB_LIST` impl class)
2. Adjust grid to cause FPM event on each row selection

   Configuration >> General settings >> "selection event type"
3. Store the selection in the main implementation class attribute at each selection
4. Read selection attribute in the `IF_FPM_GUIBB_OVS~HANDLE_PHASE_0()` OVS method

Comment: Hi and thx. 
This is an existing custom development, utilizing simple old school webdynpro. 
The FPM framework is not involved.
Meaning, I have a simple static table in the layout painter, where I somehow need to set some properties to fire that "editable cell entered" event.
If I can set them at "DO_INIT" via code.... ok ok, also nice, no problem. 
So I played around with obvious sounding properties and methods, without success.

So, what could You recommend, without FPM ?

Comment: so what `depending F4 OVS )` means?

Comment: This means: I need to get another cell value OF THAT marked row where I am in, and then filter my whole F4 content by that value, to have a smaller subset to choose from.

Comment: I understand the task but what word OVS means in this context? Are you using WDR_OVS component? It obeys [pretty the same rules](https://www.samplecodeabap.com/implementing-webdynpro-ovs/) as the FPM OVS, so the idea be the same

Comment: Using WDEVENT in the OVS callback, there is even no need to buffer the WDEVENT-OVS_CONTEXT_NODE in prior steps, just read it in step 2 . Now one more thing. Set that grid line in the UI as highlighted in the OVS....